# Is there a command to clear Intellij terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried `printf '\33c\e[3J'` or `cls` but it didn't work.
Neither `reset` works.

`clear` only jumps to the end, doesn't clear (reset) the terminal.

`ctrl` + `L` works fine, but I'm looking for a command line, not a keyboard shortcut.

In my case, I'm using Ubuntu Linux, IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3
The terminal is using Bash, but if there is another terminal or another shell that command line works, it isn't a problem for me.